# How to execute HandbrakeCLI from script?

Tags: macos, shell, path, command-line-interface, handbrake

I'm trying to execute a script that runs a Handbrake video conversion.

If I run the following command from the terminal, it works fine:

```
HandbrakeCLI -i inputtestfile.mp4 -o outputtestfile.mp4 -z "Preset"
```

If I put this into a .sh script (and give the script execution rights using chmod a+x), I get the following error:

```
HandbrakeCLI: Command not found
```

If I then put the full path to HandbrakeCLI, it then works, for example:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/handbrake/1.2.0/bin/HandBrakeCLI -i inputtestfile.mp4 -o outputtestfile.mp4 -z "Preset"
```

However, the above method is inconvenient because every time I update Handbrake to a new version, I'll have to update the script.

How can I add Path (I think this is right), to the script, so I can just use:

```
HandbrakeCLI -i inputtestfile.mp4 -o outputtestfile.mp4 -z "Preset"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can begin the `.sh` script with:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/handbrake/1.2.0/bin
```

[path](/questions/tagged/path) is an environment variable that affects where [sh](/questions/tagged/sh) would look unqualified files names (commands) from.

And for the changing version you can parse [`HandBrake --version`](https://handbrake.fr/docs/en/1.2.0/cli/command-line-reference.html) output and use it as a variable instead of `1.2.0` string in `PATH`.

Comment: thanks for the help. Some helped me solve it using "/usr/local/bin/HandBrakeCLI"

Comment: You're welcome; but are you sure that file is not being a symbolic link to the path above (which will still be affected by versioning)?